# javascript and json object

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to create an app for Google Chrome. I'm saving all the links of the visited web page in the filesystem in this way:
sorry, bad copy 
    [
 {"cur":"currentUrl","next":"nextUrl","rel": "relation"} ,{"cur":"currentUrl2","next":"nextUrl2","rel": "relation2"}
,{"cur":"currentUrl3","next":"nextUrl3","rel": "relation3"} 
...
 ]

that is the form of a json object.
Now I want to take only the first element of each array.. but how can I do it?
the result should be like this:

```
node(){
  ["currentUrl","currentUrl2", "currentUrl3" and so on..]
}
```

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. A JavaScript object consists of key value pairs and not just a comma separated list. You can validate your json here: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: sorry I put a bad copy of my code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you could do it:

```
var json = '[{"curUrl":"acme.com", "nextUrl":"acme2.com", "relation":"none"},{"curUrl":"acme3.com", "nextUrl":"acme4.com", "relation":"none"},{"curUrl":"acme5.com", "nextUrl":"acme6.com", "relation":"none"}]';

var arrCurUrls = new Array();

function getCurUrls(){
    var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(json);

    for(var i=0; i<parsedJSON.length; i++){
        arrCurUrls.push(parsedJSON[i]['curUrl']);
    }
    alert(arrCurUrls);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how your JSON should formatted.

```
[
  {
    "currentUrl": "value",
    "nextUrl": "value",
    "relation": "value"
  },
  {
    "currentUrl2": "value",
    "nextUrl2": "value",
    "relation2": "value"
  },
  {
    "currentUrl3": "value",
    "nextUrl3": "value",
    "relation3": "value"
  }
]
```

Comment: The value for a key can actually hold an array of items.